# JS Variable Scope and class change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this small little app that I built but I was wondering if there was a way to make this code more condensed/easier

```
var i = -1;
$( "#next, #back, #remove"  ).click(function () {
var filters = [ "aden", "reyes", "perpetua", "inkwell", 
"toaster", "walden", "hudson", 
"gingham", "mayfair", "lofi", 
"xpro2", "1977", "brooklyn"]

function changefilter(){
  $('figure').removeClass().addClass(filters[i]);
  $('h1').text(filters[i]);
  console.log(filters[i]);
}

if (this.id == 'next' && i < filters.length) {
 i++;
 changefilter();
} else if (this.id == 'back' && i > -1 && i !== undefined) {
    i--;
    changefilter();} else if (this.id == 'remove'){
    i = -1;
    changefilter();
    }
});
```

basically the app has 3 buttons which will cycle the class on the figure element.

I am still **really** new to javascript and I know this would have to do something with the scope but why is it that if I put the "i" variable at the very top (inside) of my function

```
var i = -1;
$( "#next, #back, #remove"  ).click(function () {
var filters = [ "aden", "reyes", "perpetua", "inkwell", 
"toaster", "walden", "hudson", 
"gingham", "mayfair", "lofi", 
"xpro2", "1977", "brooklyn"]
```

the counter does not move? Also, i put "i" to be -1 because i didn't want to have a class applied until the button was hit. Is this a good way to do this? I also noticed that when pressing the remove button the title stays at the most recent selection and does not revert back to the -1 option

Is there a way to have a variable that all functions, within a function, are able to see without making it global? Is there even a point to doing that? Am I even making sense anymore?

Thanks everyone!

If you want to see this i have a pen at http://codepen.io/Oreilly617/pen/KdrOom

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = -1;
$( "#next, #back, #remove"  ).click(function () {
    var filters = [ "aden", "reyes", "perpetua", "inkwell", "toaster", "walden", 
                    "hudson", "gingham", "mayfair", "lofi", "xpro2", "1977", "brooklyn"];

switch (this.id) {
  case 'next':
    changefilter(++i);
    break;

  case 'back':
    changefilter(--i);
    break;

  case 'remove':
      i = -1;
      $('h1').text('Fun Filter');
      break;
}

function changefilter(i){
  var length = filters.length;
  var figure = $('figure');
  var current_class = figure.prop('class');

  if (i >= 0 && $.inArray(current_class) < (length - 1)) {
    figure.removeClass(current_class);
    $('figure').addClass(filters[i])
    $('h1').text(filters[i]);
  }  
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this meets your "more condensed" but it does resolve the issue of variable scope and demonstrates creation and use of an object to contain functions etc.  Some of this is still a bit verbose but left that way for clarity.  Note that this also "cycles" through your list and returns back to the base when the next/back reach the end of the cycle as well.

Here is a fiddle if you wish to play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/9vzy3rLm/1/

```
var mything = {
    basei: -1,
    i: this.basei,
    figureSelector: 'figure.lens',
    defaultDisplay: 'Fun Filterc',
    filters: ["aden", "reyes", "perpetua", "inkwell",
        "toaster", "walden", "hudson",
        "gingham", "mayfair", "lofi",
        "xpro2", "1977", "brooklyn"],
    maxFilter: 0,
    maxFilterCalc: function () {
        this.maxFilter = this.filters.length - 1;
    },
    changefilter: function changefilter() {
        $(this.figureSelector).removeClass(this.filters.join(' ')).addClass(this.filters[this.i]);
        if (this.i == -1) {
            $('h1').text(this.defaultDisplay);
        } else {
            $('h1').text(this.filters[this.i]);
        }
    },
    processButton: function (me) {
        this.maxFilterCalc();
        if (me.id == 'next') {
            if (this.i < this.maxFilter) {
                this.i++;
            } else {
                this.i = this.basei;
            }
        } else if (me.id == 'back') {
            if (this.i > this.basei) {
                this.i--;
            } else {
                this.i = this.maxFilter;
            }
        } else if (me.id == 'remove') {
            this.i = this.basei;
        }
        this.changefilter();
    }
};
$("#next, #back, #remove").click(function () {
    mything.processButton(this);
});
```